# How to upgrade from Normal to Premium Service for UK Visas

Tags: usa, uk, vfs-global, premium-services

As per the recent suspension of biometrics enrolment for UK visas at US Application Support Centres, I wanted to upgrade from normal to premium service to use the New York Premium Application Centre. Do I have to cancel my current appointment to do that? As far as I understand, I have to cancel my current application and submit a new one, including the questionnaire.

EDIT: I was scheduled to go to ASC on Apr 17th, went straight to the Premium Centre instead, did not pay or upgrade or anything. They admitted me even though my *supposed* rescheduled date was Apr 26th. Got lucky I suppose. Proceed with caution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Officially yes, once you've booked your appointment you are meant to cancel your normal application and rebook a premium one to upgrade as stated on the [vfs website](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/us/en/how-to-apply):

> Please note: once you have selected the type of centre to attend for
>   your biometric appointment on GOV.UK, you will not be able to alter
>   your selection without cancelling your application and starting a new
>   one.